# React Testing Library for Actions in redux

Tags: react-testing-library

I am new to React Testing Library and have issue with actions.
Can anyone please guide me

I have tried below code and its giving error `Received: [Function anonymous]`

```js
export const openText = () => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.Text,
    payload: true
  });
};
```

Test Case

```js
it('open text() => {
   const expectedAction = {
      type: actionTypes.OPEN_Text,
      payload:'value
   };
   const action = actions.openText('value);
   expect(action).toEqual(expectedAction);
});
```

Error: It says `Received: [Function anonymous]`

Comment: You should post the code as part of your original question, not an answer to the question as you appear to have done.

Answer (score 0):

`React Testing Library`, as the name implies, is used for testing React components. You do not need it in this case.

You seem to be trying to test a `Redux` action creator. I suggest you follow the [async action creators section](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators) from the `Redux` docs.

Your test currently fails because you are expecting to receive an object but your action creator returns a function.

Comment: Hi doug I see u have experience with testing can u checl this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823388/expected-number-of-calls-1-received-number-of-calls-0/64823834#64823834